# How does returning value1 - value2 results in sorting?

Tags: javascript, sorting

How does returning `value1 - value2` end up in sorting, rather than returning the integral value that would be the result of mathematical substraction of the two?

```
var values = [ 213, 16, 2058, 54, 10];
values.sort(function(value1,value2){ return value1 - value2});
```

Comment: if `v1 - v2 < 0` then `v2 > v1`

Comment: Always worth reading up: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort)

Answer (score 4):

The `.sort()` method accepts a function that accepts two parameters (two elements), and returns a number to determine which element should come first. If the number is negative, `value2` is bigger. If the number is positive, `value1` is bigger. And if the number is equal to `0`, both elements are of the same size, and their order doesn't matter.

Therefore, returning `value1 - value2` only works in this case because your elements are numbers. You'd have to employ some more sophisticated logic if they were something else.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax: `[1,2,3].sort(compareFunction)`, `compareFunction` is called with two elements from the array at a time.

- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a negative number, `a` comes before `b`.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns `0`, they are equal and the two elements do not move.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a positive number, `b` comes before `a`.

See more examples and detailed documentation at MDN:

`Array.prototype.sort`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

`value1 - value2` is not what's doing the sorting. `sort` is. However, [`sort` takes a comparator parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): a function that should return something negative if the first of the two arguments is smaller, `0` if they are equal, and something positive if the first of the two arguments is greater; and `value1 - value2` does exactly that, for numeric elements.